# How to read doubles from specific location of a large file

Tags: streams, binary, import

I have a 1GB file in a proprietary format that is a mix of ASCII characters and doubles (floating point numbers). I need to read in a sequence of twelve doubles. They are in consecutive bytes of the file starting at byte 5,043,340. What is a good way to get the values of those doubles using Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use the right format for you floating point reals. E.g. with "Real64", where every number take 8 Bytes, we can write 3 numbers and then jump to the second number by:

```
str = OpenWrite["d:/tmp/test.bin", BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[str, {1., 2., 3}, "Real64"];
Close[str];
Pause[0.1];
str = OpenRead["d:/tmp/test.bin", BinaryFormat -> True];
SetStreamPosition[str, 8];
BinaryRead[str, "Real64"]
Close[str];

(* 2 *)
```